# Operator overloading inheritance with classes

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm new to coding and I'm trying to understand what is wrong with this program:

```
class Company:public Employee{
private:
    std::vector<Employee*> _table;
public:
    Company& operator+=(const Employee* emp) {
         _table.push_back(emp->clone());
          return *this;
     }
     virtual Company* clone() const {
         return new Company(*this);
     }
     virtual Company& setDescription(std::string des){
          _des=des;
     return *this;
}
```

with this in main:

```
Company* company = new Company();
a = new DeveloperEmployee(description, project);
int id = a->getID();
cout << *a << endl; //Developer ID = 2, project = hw5

company += a;
```

and I have this error :

```
   error: invalid operands of types 'Company*' and 'DeveloperEmployee*' to binary 'operator+'|
```

Comment: Please avoid pointers and silly inheritance (company->employee)

Comment: Your posted error message and posted code don't match up. There is no call to `operator+` in the posted code.

Comment: @RSahu: there is. it's not explicit though.

Answer (score 2):

You are applying the operator '+=' on a *pointer* to Company instead of a *Company* instance or reference to instance.
Dereference the pointer, for example `(*company) += a;`
will compile without complaint.

Please do not overload operators on pointers, overload on const references first, and take it from that.

Comment: thank you very much !
do you have a suggestion how to do that ??
i have to do everything to make company += a compile and run good

Comment: "i have to do everything to make company += a compile and run good" first let us get one thing out of the way: if `company` and `a` are pointers, then there simply is no way for an overload of `+=` to work.
You must mean to have `company` being an instance of `Company` and `a` an instance of `Employee`.  This can be accomplished like this, inside `Company`:
`Company &operator+=(const Employee &e) {
  _table.push_back(e.clone());
  return *this;
}`

You are using pointers unnecessarily, just use variables instead of pointer variables

Comment: understood .. sorry but the teacher changed it .. he added a pointer to company ..im sorry but its his fault...
thanks very much !!!!! you really helped me alot +1

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, using

```
Company& operator+=(const Employee* emp) {
     _table.push_back(emp->clone());
      return *this;
 }
```

to add an `Employee` to a `Company` is abuse of the semantics of the `+=` operator.

A better option will be:

```
Company& addEmployee(const Employee& emp) {
     _table.push_back(emp.clone());
      return *this;
 }
```

Then, you can use:

```
Company* company = new Company();
a = new DeveloperEmployee(description, project);
int id = a->getID();
cout << *a << endl; //Developer ID = 2, project = hw5

company->addEmployee(*a);
```

which will make the code easier to read and follow.

**Further Improvement**

Instead of using a list of pointers to `Employee`, use a list smart pointers.

```
std::vector<std::share_ptr<Employee>> _table;
```

and

```
Company& addEmployee(std::shared_ptr<Employee> emp) {
     _table.push_back(emp);
      return *this;
 }
```

and use it as:

```
Company* company = new Company();
std::shared_ptr<Employee> a(new DeveloperEmployee(description, project));
int id = a->getID();
cout << *a << endl;

company->addEmployee(a);
```

Comment: bro thanks for the help 
but i need to make company += a works and compile good
any suggestions?

Comment: @OperatorOverload, why do you "need" to support `company += a;`? It's a  bad paradigm to adopt.

Comment: @R Sahu
thats exactly what written in the exercise , im stuck there ..

Comment: @OperatorOverload, you cannot overload `+=` between two pointers. It is not allowed by the language. If your exercise calls for it, it must be a trick question.